How to morph enclosing mesh according to the enclosed mesh?
I am quite new to meshing and mesh manipulation. I am working on a problem consiting of meshes A, B, and C. The mesh C completely encloses the meshes A and B as shown in the attached figure. I applied a rigid rotation to the mesh B, and want to morph the mesh B accordingly. I have provided a simplified version of the meshes here as cylinder. (They can be complicated.)
Lets combine the meshes A and B into one mesh (say AB). For each point P_0 on C, I calculated their closest distances - d_ab (and the corresponding faces F_ab) from the mesh AB. I also calculated and stored the translation vector of each point of AB from its initial and final points positions.
Since for each P_0, I have the face F_ab, and for each of its vertices, I have a translation vector; I averaged these translation vectors for the face F_AB. Now, I have a translation vector T_p_0 for each point P_0 of C.
Now I created a translation vector T for each P_0 as a function of d_ab and T_p_0 such that T is proportional to d_ab * T_p_0.
This is a very naive solution and didn't work and also cannot work for more complicated meshes of such kind. I am starting to learn some geometrical algorithms. I am working with VTK (Visualization Toolkit Library) to work with the meshes.
It will be very helpful if I get some resources for solving this problem. Also, can we get point to point correspondences between the meshes? If yes, then how can we approach the problem with that ?
Since, I have only started learning computer graphics, please let me know if the solution I have is utterly wrong. Thanks in advance. Following are the sample images for initial and desired orientations.


